# React.js recompilation freezes, but only sometimes

Tags: reactjs

I start my React.js website by running `npm start`. When I change code, it recompiles automatically. However, sometimes it shows `Compiling...` in the terminal and freezes forever. I have to just press `Ctrl C` and run `npm start` again, which wastes a lot of time.

Sometimes this happens after a small change to the code, such as adding a `console.log` statement. I would like to provide more detail, but am not sure what it would be. How do I go about fixing this?